# VSTO - Outlook add context menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

How can I add my own Add-In to the context menu, when I do a right click on the calendar?

I have already my Add-In and a Ribbon.

I work with C# and VS2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Fluent UI to customize context menus in Outlook 2010 and later. See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information and a sample code.